# How to use Session Affinity on requests to Kubernetes service?

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-service, session-affinity

I could not find a documentation that specifies how Kubernetes service behaves when the affiliated deployment is scaled with multiple replicas.

I'm assuming there's some sort of load balancing. Is it related to the service type?

Also, I would want to have some affinity in the request forwarded by the service (i.e all requests with a certain suffix should always be mapped to the same pod if possible, etc). Is that achievable? Closes I've seen is [Ambassador](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/start/distro/ambassador), but that is affinity in the service level, and not pod level.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Deployment: Stateless workload

> I could not find a documentation that specifies how Kubernetes service behaves when the affiliated deployment is scaled with multi replicas.

Pods deployed with `Deployment` is supposed to be stateless.

### Ingress to Service routing

When using `Ingress`, L7-proxy, the routing can be based on http request content, but this depends on what implementation of an IngressController you are using. E.g. [Ingress-nginx](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/affinity/cookie/) has *some* support for *sticky sessions* and other implementations may have what you are looking for. E.g. [Istio](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/destination-rule/#LoadBalancerSettings) has support similar settings.

**Ambassador**

[Ambassador](https://www.getambassador.io/reference/core/load-balancer/) that you write about does also have *some* support for *session affinity / sticky sessions*.

> Configuring sticky sessions makes Ambassador route requests to the same backend service in a given session. In other words, requests in a session are served by the same Kubernetes **pod**

### Pod to Service routing

When a pod in your cluster does an http request to a Service within the cluster, the [kube-proxy does routing](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) in a **round robin** way by default.

> By default, kube-proxy in userspace mode chooses a backend via a round-robin algorithm.

If you want session affinity on pod-to-service routing, you can set the `SessionAffinity: ClientIP` field on a `Service` object.

> If you want to make sure that connections from a particular client are passed to the same Pod each time, you can select the session affinity based on client’s IP addresses by setting service.spec.sessionAffinity to “ClientIP” (the default is “None”).

Comment: did you actually mean "Service to Pod routing"?

Comment: Yes, do you mean Service to Pod routing? As per my understanding session affinity can be configured at the Service level in service.yaml or at the ingress level with anootations.

Comment: @Rajendra No, I mean "Pod to Service" routing. Read my answer again, I write about the service resource.

Comment: @Anand Nope, I mean "Pod to Service", e.g. cluster internal communication.